# Why is the utc offset of Los Angeles 16:07?

Tags: python, pytz

So, my code has been behaving strange. I'm trying to construct a datetime:

```
import datetime
from tzlocal import get_localzone

LOCAL_TIMEZONE = get_localzone() 

new_time = datetime.datetime(
    2019, 3, 18,
    16, tzinfo=LOCAL_TIMEZONE)

print("{}".format(new_time))
```

outputs:

```
2019-03-18 16:00:00-07:53
```

Why is the offset `-7:53`?

So, I dug in a little deeper and found this

```
>>> LOCAL_TIMEZONE
<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' LMT-1 day, 16:07:00 STD>
```

What's going on here? Am I doing something wrong? Why is Los Angeles 16:07 in tzlocal?

I'm on a Mac running Mojave.

Comment: What OS? If linux, can you provide the output of `strace python -c 'import tzlocal; tzlocal.get_localzone()'`?

Comment: @o11c mac running mojave.